# List comprehension with assignments

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I try to convert this:

```
for source in data['Source']:
    for index in range(len(source)):
        if source == sources[index]:
            percent[index] += 1
            pass
```

to this:

```
sources = [percent[index]+=1 for source in data['Source'] for index in range(len(source)) if source == sources[index]]
```

but I give an error `E0001`, after reading Python documentation I don't know how to convert this to a list comprehension.

Comment: You can't do that because you can't have a statement in comprehensions, only an expression -- and `x += y` is a statement. It would be much easier to answer you if you gave us an idea what `data['Source']` looks like, what `sources` looks like, what `percent` is before you start messing with it, and what you ultimately want to do. It may be as simple as `from collections import Counter; Counter(data['Source'])`...

Comment: what is `sources`? Why do you create the iterator `index` from `source` but then use it on `sources`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments are statements, which are not allowed in list comprehensions, which support only expressions.

You can use `sum` instead:

```
sources = {index: sum(1 for index in range(len(source)) if source == sources[index]) for source in data['Source']}
```

A more efficient method would be to use `collections.Counter`, as @Amadan has suggested in the comments:

```
import collections.Counter:
sources = Counter(index for source in data['Source'] for index in range(len(source)) if source == sources[index])
```

Comment: Because it's actually `sum(1 for index in range(len(source)) if source == sources[index])` (you're missing a right parenthesis).

Comment: true. probably you should use `enumerate` then

Comment: I did consider using `enumerate` at first but the OP isn't actually using the individual items in the `source` list at all, and is only using the index generated from `range(len(source))` to match the entire `source` list against an external list, `sources`, at the said index.

Comment: counter is only supported in python 2.7 noto work for 3.7

Comment: @MicaelDias Are you sure? https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Thanks I don't see this page!